# How do I define windows paths in volumes section in a docker-composer.yml file

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, yaml, wildfly

I am using a .yml file on Docker, in order to download and start Wildfly Server. 
I am using Windows 7 64-Bit.

The .yml file looks like the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  jboss:
    container_name: some_jboss
    build: ./wildfly/
    image: wildfly/custom
    volumes:
      - ./wildfly/deployments:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
      - ./wildfly/config/:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
      - ./wildfly/transfer/:/opt/transfer
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9990:9990
      - 7777:8787
    networks:
      - some-network
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx2g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
networks:
  some-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I used the docker command to download Wildfly Server:

```
docker-compose.exe -f myYmlFile.yml build
```

I have successfully loaded the Wildfly Server in my Docker container.

The problem occurs when I try to run the Server by using the folowing Docker command:

```
docker-compose.exe -f myYmlFile.yml up
```

The actual problem is that I become an error/exception which inform me that the 
logging.properties file could not be found. The error/exception I become is the following:

```
some_jboss | Unable to read the logging configuration from 'file:/opt/jboss/w
ildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties' (java.io.FileNotFoundExcepti
on: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties (No such file
 or directory))
some_jboss exited with code 1
```

I have checked the file and it does exist. For some reason Docker cannot understand the Windows paths defined in the volumes section in the .yml file.

Does anybody know how should windows paths be defined in order that Docker can understand them. What is the correct format?

For Linux systems the format is the following:

```
volumes:
  - ./LinuxPath:/dockerPath
```

what is the corresponding definition for windows paths?

Comment: Although you can use both `.yml` and `.yaml` as extension for the `docker-compose` file, the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since Sep 2006 on the yaml.org FAQ page. (but getting up-to-date with that respect is unfortunately not going to fix your problem)

Comment: @Anthon: Yes you are right about .yaml, but the project I am about to develop/maintain is an old project and that is what I was given. As you said, that would not solve my current problem, but thanks for the tip. I will maybe switch to .yaml in the future.